# ValueError using split in Python 3.6.5

Tags: python-3.x, split

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

I am a newb at Python.  Trying to run the following script and getting the above error on line 3.  Running this in Python 3.6.5.  Any ideas?

```
with open ('namespace.txt', 'r') as f, open ('testfile.txt', 'w') as fo:
    for line in f:
        t,y =line.split()
        fo.write(t + '\n')
        print(t)
f.close
fo.close
```

Comment: One of the lines in your text files only contains a single value, not two.

Answer (score 0):

One of your lines has 1 or 0 fields. If what you want is the first field, you could do this instead:

```
with open ('namespace.txt', 'r') as f, open ('testfile.txt', 'w') as fo:
    for line in f:
        t=line.split()
        fo.write(t[0] + '\n')
        print(t)
f.close
fo.close
```